# The language accepted by given Turing Machine

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata, regular-language, turing-machines, regular-expressions

Given a Turing Machine
$$M = (\{q_0, q_1\}, \{0, 1\}, \{0, 1, B\}, δ, B, \{q_1\})$$
Where $δ$ is a transition function defined as
$$δ (q_0, 0) = (q_0, 0, R)$$
$$δ (q_0, B) = (q_1, B, R)$$
The language $L(M)$ accepted by Turing machine is given as :

1. $0^*1^* $
2. $ 00^*$
3. $10^* $
4. $1^*0^*$

---

My attempt:

We, can draw DFA for given transition function of Turing Machine, and expression should be as $0^*$, but official key is given option $(2)\space 00^*$.

> Can you explain it, please?

Comment: Yes, this TM is a DFA and recognizes $0^*$.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi, $00^*$ is subset of $0^*$, so, this TM can also accept the language $00^*$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, $00^*$ is a subset of $0^*$, but normally one talks about *the* language accepted by a TM.  One would, however, say that the TM accepts all the strings in $00^*$.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi, I did self-answer for this post, but, someone voted down my this answer without a comment. What is bad with this answer?

Comment: I don't know what prompted the down-vote (it's not mine).  You may want to change "sting" into "strings" and replace $\in$ by $\epsilon$, tough.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$00^∗$  is subset of $0^∗$, so, this TM can also accept the all string of $00^∗$. However other than $00^∗$ only $ϵ$ is also accepted by given TM.